# Sql Distinct & count

Tags: sql, count, distinct

Hi below is my sample table "tbltemptransaction" & "tblProduct"

```
tbltemptransaction table    

userid  pid pname   description qty
3   1   HP PROBOOK 4440S    Intel Core i5   5
3   1   HP PROBOOK 4440S    Intel Core i5   3
3   6   DocuPrint C1110B    16ppm black 2
3   2   iMac 21.5"         Intel Core i5    3
tblProduct  table

PID PName                   Qty Description UnitPrice   
1   HP PROBOOK 4440S    20  Intel Core i5   2300    1    
2   iMac 21.5"          20  Intel Core i5   3999    2    
3   NEC V260 Projector  10  2700 lumens 2899    3    
4   DES-1228P Web Smart     10  24-Port     899 5    
5   DES-1210 Series          5  8-Port Web      699 5    
6   DocuPrint C1110B    15  16ppm black 899 4
```

The table where userid=3 that i can get right now where running my sql is is like this.

```
   pid  pname                    description   qty
    1   HP PROBOOK 4440S    Intel Core i5   5
    1   HP PROBOOK 4440S    Intel Core i5   3
    6   DocuPrint C1110B    16ppm black 2
    2   iMac 21.5"          Intel Core i5   3
```

May i know how to code to make it like table below ?

```
   pid  pname                    description    qty
    1   HP PROBOOK 4440S    Intel Core i5   8
    6   DocuPrint C1110B    16ppm black 2
    2   iMac 21.5"          Intel Core i5   3
```

If the pid is the same then qty will sum together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `pid`, `pname` and `description` are the same (like in your example) then `group by` will aggregate those results to one row.

```
select t.pid, t.pname, t.description, sum(t.qty) as qty
from tbltemptransaction t
group by t.pid, t.pname, t.description
```

**Edit**

```
select t.pid, sum(t.qty) as qty
from tbltemptransaction t
where pid = @userid
group by t.pid
```

@user id is a parameter for session("userid")

**Final Edit**

```
select t.pid, p.pname, p.description, sum(t.qty) as qty
from tbltemptransaction t
inner join tblproducts p on p.pid = t.pid
where t.userid = 3
group by t.pid, p.pname, p.description
```

Comment: Hi Gzaxx thanks for your reply. Actually my pname field is from another table call tblproducts. May i know how to select the data from two table where pid = session("userid") and if pid equal sum the qty.

Comment: very sorry for the invoienience, i think i ask the wrong question just now. Actually the table i show just now the data is basically come from two table tblproduct & tbltemptransction table. The result i need is actually if the userid =3 , and pid is the same , then qty for the same product will sum together. The edit question are shown above.Thanks

Comment: From which table you get `userid`?

Comment: i will get the userid from session("userid")  but for this sample i assume the userid = 3

Comment: I know that, but in you example there is not column `userid`, if I do `pid = 3` then you will only get results for `NEC V260 Projector` - is this what you want?

Comment: sorry for the mistake again , i forget to post the userid at the tbltemptransaction table. The above is the edit version of the table.

Comment: Thank you very much Gzaxx..It working great now =) Thanks a lot for your help. Have a great day ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
 select sum(qty) as qty, pid, pname, description from 
 tbltemptransaction group by pid,pname, description
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and see

```
Select distinct t1.pid,t1.name,t1.description,sum(t2.total2) From
(select pid,name,description,count(qty) as total1 from tbltemptransaction) as t1
left join (select COUNT(qty) as total2 from tbltemptransaction) as t2
on t1.pid=t2.pid
group by t1.pid,t1.name,t1.description
```